# The clientside validation error message is shown on the top of the field

Tags: webforms, 9

I'm on Drupal 9. I am using the Webform client-side validation (Select2 Jquery). Form validation error messages look good for all field types, except the *select* fields, where the validation error message is shown on the top of the drop-down field, and it's covered by the field.

> [image: Validation Error Message image]

I would like to have the validation error message at the bottom of the field, like the other fields.

Can you please suggest?